# Change value of variable which is bound with [{ngModel}] in Angular2

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I am new to Angular2 and am working on a little application. I bound a variable to a input element in a form like this:

```
<md-form-field style="display:block; width: 100%;">
  <input [required]="true" mdInput (keyup)="getType()" [(ngModel)]="typeId" placeholder="{{type}}">
</md-form-field>
```

Now I want to reset the value of *typeId* within a function like this:

```
this.ticketCreationService.saveTicket(this.typeId).then((result) => {
    if(result.protocol41){
         this.typeId = '';
    }
});
```

but (I guess because of the two way binding) the value is not resetted and the old value in the input field remains. How can I change the variable at runtime so that the input field gets updatet? Maybe this is a stupid question but I really have no clue...

Comment: your syntex seems to be ok problem may be that your code `this.typeId = '';` never get executed.

Comment: a console.log(this.typeId) was firing unfortunately... :(

Comment: did you add that console.log() inside the if statement? The syntax does seem to be fine.

Comment: Will you please post full code of the component ?

Comment: start troubleshooting by adding `console.log(result.protocol41);` above your if statement to see if the condition is actually true. You haven't posted much other code so this is just a guess, but if the `saveTicket` function is a http call, you will need to change `result.protocol41` to `result.data.protocol41`